# Process hangs while trying to read standard output

Tags: c#, xunit

As part of my automated testing (xUnit), I am trying to start a process, read its standard output, wait for it to finish, and then return the output.

The following code hangs, at the call to `WaitForExit`.

```cs
using var process = new Process {
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = $@"""{pandocPath}""",
        Arguments = $"{path} -t native --extract-media=.",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    },
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};
var ret = "";
process.OutputDataReceived += (s,e) => ret += e.Data;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
return ret;
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but calling `BeginOutputReadLine` before `WaitForExit` resolves this:

```
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```